# Doubt in understanding graphs

Tags: regression, lasso, overfitting

In [this](http://gautampendse.com/software/lasso/webpage/pendseLassoShooting.pdf) paper, on page $16$, can you please explain the plots? What kind of diagrams are these? What do we have on $x$ and $y$ coordinates in the first plot? What does the lines with very high slopes and zero slopes show?

Please help.

Comment: Left plot looks like predicted and actual y values for each sample.right plot is the coefficient values( against coefficient index, could also have used coefficient label). I doubt the lines mean much, that's just the true data

Comment: @seanv507, what is the difference between noisy and true data (red and blue lines), then?

Comment: I don't think its documented.  presumably they took the true data and added noise for testing impact